# Check if something at position X of array is a char

Tags: c++, c, arrays

```
if (selecao > 0 && selecao < 5) {
 if (assentosP[selecao] == 'O') {
     printf("Test");
```

`assentosP` is a `char` array, that has a bunch of either `D` or `O` letters (`D` by default)

```
char assentosP[2][4] = {
    {'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'}, // [0][0], [0][1], [0][2]...
    {'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'} // [1][0], [1][1], [1][2]...
};
```

What I need to know is a way to make `AssentosP` find out if the char in position `selecao` of the array is either `D` or `O`.

When I try it, it gives me a error

> iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer c

Comment: you're missing the 2nd index to the assentosP array, try to compare like: if (assentosP[selecao][0] == 'O') and you should get it

Comment: Not related to your problem, but quite important. It's better to use english names for variables/methods/classes names, especially when you decide to share your code globally. In this simple example it's not a big deal but in general non-english code is harder to understand for most of SO users.

Comment: You probably want your range check to be 'selecao >= 0 && selecao < 4' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a two dimensional array

```
char assentosP[2][4] = {
     {'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'}, // [0][0], [0][1], [0][2]...
     {'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'} // [1][0], [1][1], [1][2]...
     };
```

Thus expression `assentosP[selecao]` has type `char[4]`. You may not compare such an array with a character (or an integer after the integer promotion) like this

```
if (assentosP[selecao] == 'O') {
```

Take into account that if an array declared as having 4 elements then the valid range of indices is [0, 3]. Thus this statement

```
if (selecao > 0 && selecao < 5) {
```

looks incorrectly.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have any idea of what I should use? assentosP[selecao][] also doesn't work. I'm new to C

Comment: @JoViktor You should select a row of the array using it as the first index.

Comment: I see. I'm using a scanf("%d", selecao) that would filter by number. for instance, if the guy picks "5", then it would go to position 5 of the array. Should I use 1 scanf for the row and then 1 scanf for the column?

Comment: @JoViktor as the array has only three rows and only two of them have actual values then you can write either assentosP[0][selecao] or assentosP[1][selecao][ Of course you can also write assentosP[2][selecao]  but all elements of the row are equal to '\0'

Comment: @JoViktor You can use it like assentosP[selecao / 4][selecao % 4]]

Comment: I see, thanks! What about "the array is declared as having 3 elements"? Doesn't that array have 8 elements?

Comment: @JoViktor It is a typo.:)

Comment: Now I remember. I must declare the array as [1] for it to have 2 rows, right? because it counts from 0

Comment: @JoViktor You can declared as many rows as you like. It has nothing common with the comment to your question.

Comment: I mean, I want it to have 2 rows. So I should declare as [1], right?

Comment: @JoViktor If an declaration of an array you gave to specify the number of elements if ithere are no initializers or the number of initializers less then the number of elements of array. So if you want to have 2 rows then you have to specify 2 in the array definition. What is unclear? Reread my answer.

Comment: Sorry, my english is really bad. I think I have everything set up, thanks!